# Hajós' conjecture $(H_k)$ implies $(H_{k-1})$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a simple graph. Hajós' conjecture reads as

$(H_k)$: If $\chi(G)\geq k$, then G contains a subdivision of the complete graph $K_k$.

I am interested in understanding how exactly $(H_k)$ implies $(H_{k-1})$. If I have a $k$-colorable graph and it contains a $K_k$-subdivision, it certainly also contains a $K_{k-1}$-subdivision, but how can I use this for $k-1$-colorable graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\chi(G) \ge k-1$, and that $(H_k)$ holds.

Let $H$ be the graph $G$ with a new vertex $v$ added which is adjacent to every other vertex in $G$. Then $\chi(H) \ge k$, because $v$ must have its own color. So $(H_k)$ can be applied to get a subdivision of $K_k$ in $H$. You should check that this always gives us at least a subdivision of $K_{k-1}$ in $G$ (there are a few cases).

Also, for $k \ge 7$, $(H_k) \implies (H_{k-1})$ has a different proof: for $k \ge 7$, $(H_k)$ is false, and false statements imply anything!